# Page Flipping component for website

Tags: .net

I would like to incorporate a descent pdf viewer like this:

http://viewer.zmags.com/showmag.php?magid=174428#/page18/

for my website in order to view my pdfs.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The page looks totally like flash to me. Do you really want to replicate it in .NET?

Comment: Yes I need it to replicate it in .NET.

Comment: I want to achieve the same look and feel for viewing my pdfs in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's possible to do it in pure .Net

(it just feels like too much changes to transfer back and forward to and from the server - the processing should happen in the client)

The only technologies I know that can do this is

1. javascript... or alike
2. Ajax (which if I'm mot mistaken have a .Net framwork)... search google for "ajax .net"

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're going to need to use something along the lines of jQuery.

What you could do is setup an animation to run when you click the 'next page' button or whatever it is that you have.  Then wipe your animation from right to left (or left to right, depending on the type of language displayed on the page), and then bring in the text of your next page as well...either through some sort gradient fade in or shift or whatnot.